# Prolog: Differentiate between number and letter list

Tags: prolog

I need to write a list that must contain more than 3 elements if the elements are not numbers and if the elements are numbers, it must contain exactly 3 elements and the third element must be the result of the addition of first and second element. This is what I have:

```
mylist([W, X,Y,Z|_]). % List contains at least 3 Elements
mylist([X,Y,Z]):- Z is X+Y. % if there are 3 numbers, third number is the addition of first and second
```

Problem is that this is too general and works only partially. It will match mylist(3,3,3) because of the first fact though it should not, since this is a numbers' list and it should say no. But I don't know how I can differentiate between a numbers' list and a letters' list

Comment: What should be the result in mylist([1,2,A]). which has two numbers and a letter? If it has at least one number then from your description the list should only has numbers and has length 3 right??

Comment: Sorry, my mistake ( I edited the question to reflect this). It must contain more than 3 elements (length > 3) if it is not a number. If it is a number, then it must contain exactly 3. So, mylist([1,2,A]) will be no since it contains only 3 elements and not all are numbers.

Comment: Do you want to say "if at least one element is not number" ?? because else what about [1,2,A,B] it has length >3 and not all numbers...

Comment: [1,2,A,B] should be yes since it has length  >3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use number/1 which succeeds when the argument is a number:

```
mylist([_, _,_,_|_]). 
mylist([X,Y,Z]):- number(X),number(Y),number(Z),Z =:=X+Y.
```

Now mylist([3,3,3]) fails:

```
?- mylist([3,3,3]).
false.
```

Comment: You really should use `Z =:= X + Y` instead, with `is`, for example this fails: `2 is 1.5 + 0.5`. `is/2` is **not a comparison**!

Comment: Yes boris you have absolutely right i will edit the post thanks!!